# I hav a tcl dict with key and value pair, where value is list and I want to check if the new value is already present or not?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

```
set a [dict create]
set key abc
set value bb

dict set $a $key $value
Ans:- abc bb
```

but when I try:

```
dict exists $a $key bb
```

It returns 0. ?

Could you help me get the right syntax for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract the list value and use the `in` operator to test that the value is included in the list:

```
if {$value in [dict get $a $key]} {
    puts "$value is in the list"
}
```

More verbosely, you could use

```
if {[lsearch -exact [dict get $a $key] $value] != -1} {
```